# Get a picture from a word under cursor for OCR processing

Tags: c#, c++, ocr, tesseract

Hi Fox
I want to detect the word under cursor with get image from it(like babylon). But i don't know how can i get the area of screen for grab word that under cursor.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want an answer for C++ or C#? If you need answers for both, better post seperate questions. So decide and remove the inappropriate tag here, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is done via Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA). You don't do it yourself in your program.

Since it's COM-based, you can do it from both C++ and C#.

(Assuming Windows since it's tagged C#)